# Need a web based file uploader

Tags: ftp, file-sharing, file-transfer, upload

I have a RedHat server, running tomcat and a video streaming application ( Adobe FMS ).

I have several dozens of users who would like to be able to upload their videos to this server.  But I don't want to give them access, and even if I did some of them are not technical enough to use a client like WinSCP.

I am looking for a web based file uploader, that will allow my users to upload their video files to the server.

It is an absolute requirement that the users be able to create new directories.

Ideally, I would be able to authenticate using our LDAP, but I suppose I could use Apache htaccess rules to protect the uploader.

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at [SwfUpload](http://swfupload.org/).

SWFUpload is a small JavaScript/Flash library to get the best of both worlds.
It features the great upload capabilities of Flash and the accessibility and
ease of HTML/CSS.

Best regards, Phil.

Comment: When you say "best of both worlds", which two worlds would that be?

Comment: The "evil" world of flash, which is proprietary, but nearly runs everywhere. And the open world of HTML and CSS which will work in nearly all browsers. :-)

Answer (score 0):

[Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) has a web-based file uploader, including the ability to make new directories. You'll have to look into the authentication part, though.

Make sure you're *just* enabling the remote file uploading. Webmin can be used for administering a server in its entirety, and can be very dangerous to leave open otherwise. I don't use it personally, but the features may be worth it in your case.

Answer (score 0):

depends on what is your intension here. Are they just users for your front end website only? if so there are a few based on php that you can include into your web front.

Webmin/Usermin does the job for you BUT in order to use Usermin, every user has to have an account on your REDHAT, judging from what you wrote. I doubt u want thousands of accounts in your redhat system :D

have a look at net2ftp, its php based, create a service account and a repository for it and wallah. you have yourself a webfront ftp download/upload area.

NOTE: some tweaking and customization might have to be done here though, im no php developer so sorry i cant help that much there

Answer (score 0):

We use [PHPFileNavigator](http://pfn.sourceforge.net/) (pfn) which is easy to install and to use. You can make administrators and 'ordinary' users. You can disable/allow finely grained who is allowed to do what.

We don't use LDAP for authentication, but it seems somebody made a patch to allow for LDAP auth,

see [this link](http://pfn.sourceforge.net/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=9540&sid=7f5e144962469a704b71a90758bd7336) to see a discussion about this patch.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend [w2box](http://clement.beffa.org/labs/projects/w2box/). Nice UI file upload tool written in PHP, and it's free.